# MySQL #1064 error on line 2

Tags: mysql, errors

I'm quite new on learning SQL and I seem to be running into an issue with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `read`
  (`order` NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`title`,`url`)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

It's returning the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, `url` VARCHAR(50' at line 2

Comment: I can't seem to answer my own question at this point but I figured it out. Adding `INT` after `order` solves it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You hadn't defined a datatype for column `order`. And why have you accepted that answer? It doesn't explain what is wrong, it removes the `UNIQUE` constraint, it changes the `PRIMARY KEY`. Not very helpful. Do you know you can post an answer yourself?

Comment: @ypercube Smart catch on the answer below. I ended up just using my own answer. However, I can't answer my own question as I don't have enough 'reputation' to do so.

Comment: Oh yes, I think you need to have 15 reputation to do that or wait a few hours (or both, not sure.)

Comment: @ypercube 10 rep points to answer or wait like 8 hours or something. I was able to get to 11 but now have to wait to accept my own answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `read`
  (`order` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`title`,`url`)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

I was missing `INT` after `order`

Answer (score 3):

Try like below, it will help you...

```
CREATE TABLE `read`
  (`order` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`order`)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a difference between `INT` and `MEDIUMINT`?

Comment: Yes. It is. difference mainly on storage space. for more read have a look into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Why did you change the primary key definition?